# adding data to layout.cshtml from index.cshtml at a specific location in layout.cshtml

Tags: asp.net-mvc, layout, razor, master-pages

I have a `layout page` in `shared` folder of my `mvc application`. The name of the page is `Layout.cshtml`

I have `two div tags` in `Layout.cshtml` namely `div1` and `div2`.

I have a `controller` called `membersController`.
This controller sends list of `two types of members` to view. i.e. `GeneralMembers` and `AdminMembers.`

I have a `view` called `Index.cshtml` in members folder.

In this view I get the data as expected. But the only problem is that `I dont know how to get that two lists inside of each div`. In short I want to have `GeneralMembers` in `div1` and `AdminMembers` in `div2`.

There might be duplicates of this question but I dont know the keywords/query to search for on google.

If anyone knows any tutorials then please post the link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If model you send to View from your Controller Action contains two lists, you may call each of them in your View. For example:

```
<div class="div1">
<ul>
@foreach (var i in model.GeneralMembers)
<li>@i.Name .......</li>
</ul>
</div>

<div class="div2">
<ul>
@foreach (var i in model.AdminMembers)
<li>@i.Name .......</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

ADDED:
In that case may me you can use jQuery. In your Index page use hidden div:

```
<script>
$('.Indexdiv1').hide();

</script>
<div class="Indexdiv1">
    <ul>
    @foreach (var i in model.GeneralMembers)
    <li>@i.Name .......</li>
    </ul>
    </div>
```

And on your Layout page append html from Indexdiv1 to div1:

```
    <script>
     $(document).ready(function()
{
    $('.div1').append($('.Indexdiv1').html())
});

    </script>

    <div class="div1"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for trying to answer my question but This is not my problem. My problem is that I have `div1` and `div2` in Layout page. and I get lists on the index page. Now I want to show that lists in these divs.